# python login 163 mail server

Tags: python, email, imap

When I use this script to login the 163 mail server,there is something wrong!
My python env is python 2.7.8
Please help me!

```
import imaplib

def open_connect(verbose=False):
    host = 'imap.163.com'
    port = 993
    if verbose:print 'Connecting to',host
    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
    username = 'tmailest@163.com'
    passwd = 'aaannnmmm'
    if verbose:print 'Logging in as',username
    try:
        connection.login(username,passwd)
    except Exception as err:
        print 'ERROR:', err

    return connection

c = open_connect()

try:
    tye,data = c.select('INBOX')
    print tye,data
    num_msgs=int(data[0])
    print 'There are %d messages in INBOX' % num_msgs
finally:
    c.close()
    c.logout()
```

=====

```
NO ['SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imap_select.py", line 26, in <module>
    c.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 382, in close
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('CLOSE')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 825, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))
imaplib.error: command CLOSE illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

=====
And then  the 163 mail server send me a mail,about this:

```
该行为存在以下安全隐患：
1） 邮件客户端未经有效识别，不能有效保证帐户安全性，存在帐号密码泄漏的风险；
2） 数据传输安全性低，存在数据泄漏风险。
```

In English is :

```
1) mail client not a security client 
2) data streaming is notsecruity
```

Thanks a lot.
This is the debug info .
I think that I must a have a TLS1.2 version conection.

```
  05:59.52 > ENFK1 LOGIN "tmailest@163.com" "aaannnmmm"
  05:59.54 < ENFK1 OK LOGIN completed
  05:59.54      matched r'(?P<tag>ENFK\d+) (?P<type>[A-Z]+) (?P<data>.*)' => ('ENFK1', 'OK', 'LOGIN completed')
  05:59.54 > ENFK2 SELECT INBOX
  05:59.54 < ENFK2 NO SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi
  05:59.54      matched r'(?P<tag>ENFK\d+) (?P<type>[A-Z]+) (?P<data>.*)' => ('ENFK2', 'NO', 'SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi')
  05:59.54 NO response: SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi
NO ['SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imapselect.py", line 31, in <module>
    c.close()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 375, in close
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('CLOSE')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1060, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 818, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))
imaplib.error: command CLOSE illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

Answer (score 4):

After netease blocking your own client, they will send you an email named **网易邮箱提醒：阻止了一次不安全的收信请求** by `mail@service.netease.com`.

On the bottom of the email, they provided a link to the configure page:

http://config.mail.163.com/settings/imap/index.jsp?uid=YOUR_EMAIL_NAME@126.com

Replace **YOUR_EMAIL_NAME** by yourself.

Comment: I've just checked: to "configure" your mail clients to login, you have to sell out your phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Netease is promoting their new mobile email app "邮箱大师", and they currently blocked any imap client other than their offical clients and several popular clients such as thunderbird, foxmail.
I don't know how do they identified the client. Anyway, may it's time for you to switch to other email service provider. At least QQ mail works well.

Comment: NO,I think Netease do this for security.

Comment: @nihan Netease applied this blocking policy around late 2014, and I'm pretty sure your code will work well with qq mail(their problem is a crippled support for IMAP search). I'm a long time netease email service user, but I don't neccessary always stand on their side. You can verify my words, and once agreed, pls mark mine as the answer.

Comment: @nihan no, for security SSL is good. For security the "update" link should be in HTTPS. I can use openssl or python to connect to Gmail just fine. For security netease shouldn't have modify my mails for ads (that's why I switched to Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the debug output produced by your IMAP library. It seems that the server administrators have configured their server to always reject LOGIN even though you are on a secure SSL connection. That's an interesting choice, but some providers do that. Talk to their support about how you are supposed to connect to their service.

Comment: I think  i must have a more safely imaplib .

Comment: @nihan: no they say you should use vendor-chosen clients that can't do a lot of things you want.

Answer (score 0):

The configure URL may be changed or forbidden by Netease corporation.
"http://config.mail.163.com/settings/imap/index.jsp?uid=YOUR_EMAIL_NAME@<163 or 126>.com" is now a login web page. after password input, it redirects to your mailbox, NOT THE CONFIGURE WEB PAGE.