# Android:javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 NO SELECT Unsafe Login

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, imap

Javamail first time to receive NetEase mail, there will be this error , the internet search a lot of information and found that need to verify, but this link does not seem to verify the link, the link into the next :

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797705/python-login-163-mail-server)

Error log:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 NO SELECT Unsafe Login. Please contact kefu@188.com for help;
>                                                                               nested exception is:
>                                                                               com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A3 NO SELECT Unsafe Login. Please contact kefu@188.com for help
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1071)
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:999)
>                                                                                 at com.chaoxing.email.service.MailHelper.getAllEmailUIDList(MailHelper.java:454)
>                                                                                 at com.chaoxing.email.utils.EmailPollUtil$1.run(EmailPollUtil.java:96)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                              Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A3 NO SELECT Unsafe Login. Please contact kefu@188.com for help
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:397)
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.select(IMAPProtocol.java:1245)
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1056)
>                                                                                 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:999) 
>                                                                                 at com.chaoxing.email.service.MailHelper.getAllEmailUIDList(MailHelper.java:454) 
>                                                                                 at com.chaoxing.email.utils.EmailPollUtil$1.run(EmailPollUtil.java:96) 
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

What should I do?

Comment: you did not see "contact kefu@188.com for help"?

Comment: Are you using SSL or StartTLS?

Comment: "contact kefu@188.com for help" .
haha,It's not ok.

Comment: Yes,I use SSL.
I know need to verify, but do not know how to configure, that link can still be before, but now it was

Comment: Thank you, I think about other ways.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my own, I found that if it is a mobile phone number, you need to bind their own letter of the mailbox, the link can be verified through